# Showing convergence of and evaluating an integral.

Tags: convergence-divergence

I want to show that the following integral is convergent, and evaluate it:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{1}{7 + \tan(x)} dx$$.

I plugged the limit into mathematica and got "Directed Infinity". Tried the trick of multiplying the integral by $1$ and see if something more elucidating would come up, but nothing.

The book I got this from says that this limit is for "high $T$", which I interpreted as $T$ goes to infinity. Maybe that could be the problem, nonetheless, I don't see how this limit is done.

Thank you ! :)

Comment: $\displaystyle\large{7\pi - 2\ln\left(7\right) \over 100} \approx 0.1810$.

Comment: [Use this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Answer (score 1):

Using  Felix Marin's suggestion, you could show that $$\int \dfrac{1}{a + \tan(x)} dx=\frac{a x+\log (a \cos (x)+\sin (x))}{a^2+1}$$ from which it follows that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{1}{a + \tan(x)} dx=\frac{\pi  a-2 \log (a)}{2 a^2+2}$$ which does not make any problem as long as $a$ is greater than $0$.